# ESP32 Networking: Can't send TCP answer without losing socket connection

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, esp32

Morning!
So I'm pretty new to networking stuff and I think I got a bit overwhelmed. I'm pretty bad at titles too, I guess I'm not losing the connection when sending stuff but before, and it's just throwing an error when I try to.

So here's my problem: on my ESP32 board, I'm setting up a TCP listener (see below). I'm creating and binding the socket and then wait for incoming connections. A python script on my laptop will then connect and send a TCP packet with some content that my board then processes by a) leaving the shared WiFi, b) connecting to a new one where some stuff is done, including opening and closing a UDP connection, c) joining the first WiFi again to then send an answer back to my laptop.

```
static void tcp_server_task(void *pvParameters)
{
    char rx_buffer[256];
    char addr_str[128];
    int addr_family;
    int ip_protocol;

    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(TCP_PORT);
    addr_family = AF_INET;
    ip_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;
    inet_ntoa_r(dest_addr.sin_addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str) - 1);

    int listen_sock = socket(addr_family, SOCK_STREAM, ip_protocol);
    if (listen_sock < 0) 
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Unable to create socket: errno %d", errno);
    }

    else
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Socket created");

        int err = bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
        if (err != 0) 
        {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Unable to bind socket: errno %d", errno);
        }

        else
        {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Socket bound, port %d", TCP_PORT);

            while (1) 
            {
                err = listen(listen_sock, 1);
                if (err != 0) 
                {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error occurred during listen: errno %d", errno);
                    break;
                }
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Socket listening");

                struct sockaddr_in6 source_addr;
                uint addr_len = sizeof(source_addr);
                int sock = accept(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&source_addr, &addr_len);
                if (sock < 0) 
                {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Unable to accept connection: errno %d", errno);
                    break;
                }
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connection accepted");

                while (1) 
                {
                    int len = recv(sock, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer) - 1, 0);

                    // Error occurred during receiving
                    if (len < 0) 
                    {
                        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "recv failed: errno %d", errno);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Connection closed
                    else if (len == 0) 
                    {
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connection closed");
                        break;
                    }

                    // Data received
                    else 
                    {
                        // Get the sender's IP address as string
                        if (source_addr.sin6_family == PF_INET) 
                        {
                            inet_ntoa_r(((struct sockaddr_in *)&source_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str) - 1);
                        } 
                        else if (source_addr.sin6_family == PF_INET6) 
                        {
                            inet6_ntoa_r(source_addr.sin6_addr, addr_str, sizeof(addr_str) - 1);
                        }

                        rx_buffer[len] = 0; // Null-terminate whatever we received and treat like a string
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received %d bytes from %s:", len, addr_str);
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s", rx_buffer);

                        wifi_disconnect();
                        join_other_wifi();
                        open_udp_socket();
                        output = generate_output();         
                        close_udp_socket();
                        wifi_disconnect();
                        join_old_wifi_again();          

                        int err = send(sock, output, sizeof(output), 0);
                        if (err < 0) 
                        {
                            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error occurred during sending: errno %d", errno);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (sock != -1) 
                {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Shutting down socket and restarting...");
                    shutdown(sock, 0);
                    close(sock);
                }
            }
            vTaskDelete(NULL);                  
        }       
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the TCP connection seems to be timed out when I'm ready to send back an answer as I'm getting a `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]` on my laptop and `Error occured during sending: errno 113` on the board as soon as I try to. 
Any idea how to fix this? The python script on my laptop just waits for the answer on the same socket that it sent the first packet with, on a rather long timeout. So Idk, did the board close the connection? How am I supposed to re-open the connection with my board without changing the python script when my board can't establish connections itself and only waits for others to connect to it?

Or am I able to start a connection with the IP and the port? I already tried to open a TCP client socket on the same IP/port to send to it and just hope that the TCP client on the laptop interpretes this as a response from the TCP server on the board, however it was unable to connect.

Comment: you disconnect from the WiFi network and expect the socket still be connected after connecting back? at disconnection all sockets are closed and servers stopped

Comment: Should have guessed so. Any idea on how to reconnect? Opening a new socket on my board to the same IP / port didn't work.

Comment: the client must initiate the connection

Comment: I should say that I got what I have from someone who worked on it before with other boards, I'm just adapting it to ESP32, so I know that it *should* work in some way or another (will speak with him soon about it). I'm giving the board a command with parameters over TCP and the board then gathers some physical data about some stuff, for that it's necessary to do the WiFi switch / UDP connection. After gathering the data I want the board to reconnect to the TCP socket on the laptop and respond with the data, so that the program then processes these. BTW, why is it a disadvantage to mix UDP/TCP?

Comment: Jeah, I think I found it - was kinda buried in the code. The board has to send a response before disconnecting from the WiFi so that the program knows that it has to switch to a TCP listener. I guess the board as a client can then establish a connection. Thanks for your time!